# How could Android Instant Apps affect the existing app?

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, android-instant-apps

1. How will the Instant app affect the already existing app ? When its out in the market does it mean that all the existing app must be made compatible to be behave like instant app ?
2. Does anyone has any idea if these could be integrated with the Hybrid apps?
3. Will it be using the run-time permission mode ?
4. What will happen to the games app and other apps that has information stored about the progress of the players and the current state ?
5. Does this seems to be the future of the apps? What is the actual benefit in having the instant app?

Comment: These will be fine questions sometime **after Instant Apps exist**. Right now, it is merely a set of statements made at a conference and [a very short FAQ](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html).

Answer (score 2):

Instant Apps documentation has been published: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html

Instant Apps are opened through URLs. If the app is installed, then this behaves like a normal deep link. If the app is not installed, the Instant App can be launched instead.

Instant Apps must support runtime permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Android Instant Apps enables native Android applications to run in response to launching a URL, without installing the app. Instant apps can use many Android APIs and you use Android Studio to build them.

**How do they work?** When Google Play receives a request for a URL that matches an instant app, it sends the necessary code files to the Android device that sent the request. The device then runs the app.

**Note:** Android Instant Apps only work on Android devices running on Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher.

[Reference:- android Developer Instant app](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/overview.html)